# iSCSI connection timing out on ESX 3.5 against a NetApp storage appliance

Tags: networking, vmware-esx, iscsi, netapp

I get a timeout on iSCSI on different ESX hosts (3.5) at different times. It is puzzling, as both the ESX hosts as windows and other guests are experiencing timeouts.

The iSCSI network is segregated on a private network.

Here is an export of vmkiscsid.log from last night:

```
2010-02-10-12:30:38: iscsid: an InitiatorAlias= is required, but was not found in /etc/vmware/vmkiscsid/initiatorname.iscsi
2010-02-10-12:30:38: iscsid: LogLevel = 0
2010-02-10-12:30:38: iscsid: LogSync = 0
2010-02-10-12:30:42: iscsid: Login Success: iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.101197719,default,192.168.73.2,3260,2001, 0x1
2010-02-10-12:30:42: iscsid: connection1:0 is operational now
2010-02-16-02:03:35: iscsid: Kernel reported iSCSI connection 1:0 error (1008) state (3)
2010-02-16-02:03:39: iscsid: connection1:0 is operational after recovery (2 attempts)
2010-02-16-04:02:27: iscsid: Kernel reported iSCSI connection 1:0 error (1008) state (3)
2010-02-16-04:02:32: iscsid: connection1:0 is operational after recovery (2 attempts)
```

Should i edit the timeout value on the ESX host for iSCSI? This may work around the problem but will not solve it.

Comment: Problems like these are better suited to either your SAN vendor or VMware, as they probably know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

disable iscsi pings, as explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/30657/xen-domu-root-filesystems-becoming-read-only-on-iscsi-virtual-ip-failover)

Answer (score 0):

You not only need a VMKernel Port but also the Console Port to access the iSCSI Portal.

Is there a Service Console Port in the iSCSI LAN? Or do you route your Traffic from the Console to the iSCSI Portal? Maybe there´s something between Service Console and iSCSI Portal that adds delay and/or timeouts.